# xamarin forms image not showing image in listview by URL sometimes

Tags: image, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm using xamarin forms V3.4.0.1029999

I have a listview that it contains Image control.

I Pass image source by an string Property. sometimes listview wont show image By URL. i mean for example it shows 39 items but 2.

Sometimes it wont load image from URL.
what should i do to always load image?

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve], and maybe some screenshots of what you're getting now?

Comment: Please post code that you done.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you use [FFImageLoading's](https://github.com/luberda-molinet/FFImageLoading#ffimageloading---fast--furious-image-loading) CachedImage for this.

It is a library that is vastly accepted by the community and is great with caching and has memory handling options as well.

You can check their [Git wiki](https://github.com/luberda-molinet/FFImageLoading/wiki) to understand the library in depth.

Download it form [Nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.FFImageLoading/)

Call `CachedImageRenderer.Init()` on each platform. Let’s put it on `MainActivity.cs` of our Android project and `AppDelegate.cs` of iOS.

Then add its namespace and use it like this:

```
  <ffimageloading:CachedImage
                HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center"
                DownsampleToViewSize="true"
                Source = "{Binding ImageUrl}">
        </ffimageloading:CachedImage>
```