# Image not shown in Xamarin android

Tags: xaml, xamarin

This is the content of my *.xaml* file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             x:Class="App1.MainPage">

    <StackLayout>
        <Label Text="HelloWorld"></Label>
        <Image Source="https://placehold.it/100"></Image>
    </StackLayout>

</ContentPage>
```

This is how it looks:

[image]

And this is my project settings:

[image]

I don't have a mac to see if the problem exists in iOS or not.

Comment: check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54647346/xamarin-forms-image-not-showing-image-in-listview-by-url-sometimes/54648604#54648604

Comment: @FreakyAli This doesn't explain what's the problem in my case.

Comment: This is a known issue with the Xamarin.Forms Image control that it does not work well with URL's, Also you might wanna consider the fact that your image itself does not have public access or is hosted privately

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Updating from Xamarin.Forms 4.2 to Xamarin.Forms 4.3 fixed it.

Comment: Thanks you a lot

Answer (score 0):

It's a common issue. In the majority of the cases this is due to a bad link. 
Try an url where the extension of the image is specified like this:

"https://secure.webtoolhub.com/static/resources/icons/set113/55ba4962.png"

or, instead, try to add '.png' at the end of the url you're currently using.

I've noticed that if you use an url where the extension is not specified, the application has some issue to renderize the image.

Comment: I've changed the link with your link. and still the same issue.

Comment: <Image Source="https://placehold.it/100.png" HeightRequest="300" />

Try to set the HeightRequest: this tells to the system which dimension the image should have. The WidthRequest is not needed because the aspect ratio is preserved by default.

Also, if you don't put anything between the tags of a component, it's a bad practice to use the extended declaration. Use the short declaration as shown above.

Comment: The code in your comment makes the app crashes, I added https:// to the start of the link, now the app doesn't crash, but still, no image appear.

Comment: Yes, it was clearly an example. Of course, you have to use the complete url.
Try another url, like the one I've posted in the first answer and you'll see that should do it.

Comment: Another issue could be that the site where is hosted the image uses https as protocol, while for the image itself is used http or reverse. 

Here is explained more in detail: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/105036/images-from-url-not-showing-on-android